# Laravel 5.5 Blade route() parameter

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

Can I add a parameter which I can use in a blade template, and which doesn't appear in the url?

```
route("Home", ['id' => 1]);

@if(isset($id))
    //Do something
@endif
```

Comment: Where is that parameter coming from then? Is it from a related table to "home"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. instead of `route()` is used `redirect()`

```
redirect()->with(['id' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 22):

I had need to create route in view and to send parameter that route.

I did it this way:

```
{{route('test', $id)}}
```

[This article helped me.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-i-pass-parameter-in-route-hrefroutetestval-to-blade-view?page=0)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in parameters just like that yes, but they will be included in the url:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes

> If the named route defines parameters, you may pass the parameters as
> the second argument to the route function. The given parameters will
> automatically be inserted into the URL in their correct positions:

```
Route::get('user/{id}/profile', function ($id) {
    //
})->name('profile');

$url = route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

To pass parameters without including them in the url you will need to add the parameters in the controller/router method, and not within the `route()` method. Eg:

```
Route::view('/welcome', 'welcome', ['name' => 'Taylor']);
```